# Installing KolibriOS on a flash stick using GRUB2

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, grub2

KolibriOS can be installed and booted from an USB stick. Its developers say it's possible to use GRUB2, from hard drive or USB drive, but it's not described how to do in the documentation that for a USB stick. However, they say it's pretty similar to booting it from a hard drive. From a hard drive, I'd have to add this to `/etc/grub` (grub.d):

```
menuentry "KolibriOS" {
       set root='(hd0,5)'    # edit this to your correct partition, given example is sda5
       linux16 /memdisk
       initrd16 /kolibri.img
}
```

- How can I do that for an USB stick?
- How can I find that out?
- Where should I start off?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to tell grub where to find the partition (your USB) which contains the operating system. For the purpose of this answer, I will assume that GRUB is installed on the USB stick. As per [Arch Linux's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Manual_configuration), it is best to have GRUB read the UUID at boot time, by adding this to the top of your grub.cfg file:

```
# path to the partition holding ISO images (using UUID)
probe -u $root --set=rootuuid
set imgdevpath="/dev/disk/by-uuid/$rootuuid"
insmod search_fs_uuid
search --no-floppy --set=isopart --fs-uuid $rootuuid
```

Now, you can tell GRUB where to find the necessary files:

```
menuentry "KolibriOS" {
    linux16 ($isopart)/path/to/memdisk
    initrd16 ($isopart)/path/to/kolibri.img
}
```

If you want to boot the ISO file directly as a LiveCD, you can use the following instead:

```
menuentry "KolibriOS" {
    loopback loop ($isopart)/path/to/KolibriOS.iso
    linux16 /path/to/memdisk
    initrd16 (loop)/kolibri.img
}
```

I have successfully tested the LiveCD option, but never tested the installed version, although it should work too.